# What is the ideal structure for handling nonce?

Tags: c#

I would like to keep track of a .... of [nonces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). It should track the nonce value and the expiration date. The structure should allow for fast lookup of the nonce, like a Dictionary, but allow for reasonably efficient cleanup, e.g., pop the expired nonces and stop when you no longer need to pop them. What do you recommend? Expiration hacks (e.g., a limited size rotating buffer) are good too.

Comment: Loading strictly in memory seems like potential problems...maybe Memcache with a DB fallback?  But, in any case, this is probably going to get flagged as an out of scope (or whatever) question since the "best way" is going to be subject to opinion.

Comment: Do you mean a *collection* of nonces?

Comment: @ApceHHypocrite, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce

Answer (score 5):

Without further information about typical usage patterns, a Dictionary keyed by the nonce containing the expiration as a value and a reverse lookup of exipration time to a set of nonces that expire at that time seems most efficient.

If you know something about the lifetime of nonces and the stage within that lifetime they are typically accessed, it may be more efficient to use the following strategy instead:

- Have buckets that represent an expiration time range.
- In each bucket, have a dictionary keyed by the nonce, with the value being the expiration time.
- When a nonce comes in, look it up in the most recent bucket first.  If not there, check additional buckets in order of expiration.
- If you find a nonce in a bucket, verify that it's expiration date has not passed.
- Cleanup is as simple of disposing buckets that are past the allowed nonce duration.

The disadvantage of this solution is that you potentially examine several buckets to find a given nonce, and that you examine every bucket for an invalid nonce.  The advantage is that you avoid the need for an index from expiration date to list of nonces expiring then for efficient cleanup.  To tune the bucket size (in terms of a timespan), you should have some idea of when during the lifetime of a nonce it is likely to be used.

Note that, if the nonce validation needs to survive a server restart or work in a server farm you will want some form of permanent storage (e.g. a database).  You would still use the same strategies.

Comment: Adding to this since the OP mentioned that "hacks" were acceptable, if you can guarantee that nonces are being added in increasing order of expiration time, a hash table keyed by the nonce value as well as a parallel linked list (naturally in order of increasing expiration time) will allow you to quickly remove the nonces head-first from the list as time goes on.

Comment: I like the buckets suggestion for easy clean-up, and no, this does not need to survive server restart or work in a server farm.